# How to get line breaks from textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea, line-breaks

I have the following form:

```
<form action='somepage.php' method='post'>
<textarea name='sendto' rows='4' cols='30'></textarea>
</form>
```

A typical answer to this part of the form would be:

```
John Smith
123 Street name
Suburb, Postcode
```

I want to keep this as a text box and not just 4 separate inputs, but when I go the next page, the variable `$_POST['sendto']` comes out as a single line of text. How can I keep the new lines in the input received from the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function. It will format your input the exact way you'd written in your text area.

When you're retrieving your POST data, write this:

```
echo nl2br($_POST['sendto']);
```

Comment: wow, that's easy! Thanks heaps. Soon as SO lets me tick your answer I'll tick it. Thanks for the link too :)